# Separando uma String sem delimitador definido

Tags: php, mysql

Preciso de uma certa ajuda, tenho uma String ex: 95YAH0T01MJ456348 - essa String sempre conterá 17 dígitos e a String deve ser separada sempre nos primeiros 6 dígitos para pode pegar e fazer uma comparação no banco de dados para identificar o modelo. Porém não achei nenhuma função que faça essa separação, nem no PHP nem no SQL(MYSQL).

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: Consegui com seu comentário, super simples, obrigado!

Comment: Apenas para tornar claro: sua string (95YAH0T01MJ456348) contém 17 caracteres mas apenas 11 dígitos. Talvez você esteja confundindo a nomenclatura. Se pode conter uma mistura de caracteres e você deseja considerar apenas 6 dígitos a posição aonde separar pode variar. Defina clara e precisamente seu problema.

Answer (score 3):

Como dito nos comentários use a função [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) para retornar uma parte de uma string.

Essa função possui a seguinte assinatura:

**`substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] ) : string`**

Onde:

- `$string`: É a string cujo a parte deve ser retornada.
- `$start` : É o índice onde começa a parte da substring a ser retornada.
- `$length`: É o comprimento da substring a ser retornada.

> No manual de [`substr()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) há outras considerações importantes a respeito dos parâmetros `$start` e `$length`.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$s = "95YAH0T01MJ456348";

//O primeiro elemento, onde o índice é zero, são os seis primeiros caracteres de $s 
//o segundo elemento, cujo índice é um, são os caracteres remanescentes.
$res = [substr($s, 0, 6), substr($s, 6)];

print_r($res);

?>
```

Resultando:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 95YAH0
    [1] => T01MJ456348
)
```